# What is the equivalent of ReDimStatement in c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

In `vb.net` I've this code block:

```
Public Sub AddItem(Text As String, Optional Left As Integer = 0, Optional Header As Boolean = False)
    Dim Item As ListItem
    ReDim Item.Text(0)
    Item.Text(0).Text = Text
    Item.Text(0).Left = Left
    Item.Header = Header
    LstItems.Add(Item)
End Sub
```

**UPDATE: ListItem**

```
Public Structure ListItem
    Dim Text() As ListText
    Dim Header As Boolean
End Structure
```

this code allow me to add an item to a list, `ReDim` allocate the storage space for an array variable in vb.net, in c# what is the equivalent of this code? I also tried to convert it on [converter.telerik.com](http://converter.telerik.com/) without success.

Comment: I worked in vb.net for 5 years and never used `ReDim`. What type is `ListItem`?

Comment: @dotNET Is there a duplicate w/o `Preserve`? I think this is simple `new` array

Comment: @CoderDennis is a struct, let me update. This code is an old windows form (vb.net) custom control. I'm trying to convert the codebase in c# and reuse it in wpf.

Comment: Use a List object instead of an array.  Don't need to redim.

Comment: @Dillinger `Item.Text = new ListText[1];`

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for this, I will try when the conversion is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ReDim Item.Text(0)
```

in VB is the same as

```
Item.Text = new String[1];
```

in C#.  But you might want to take a step back here and ask what the program is actually doing, and then write a more idiomatic C# program. In particular, should Text be a `List<string>` instead of an array?